# Only pass GET information if isset

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using a form with the method of GET to add to the query string.

I am running into an issue. When the form is submitted every field is sent and added to the query including with no values.

Example:

```
http://web.com/?filter-types=news&filter-document-type=&filter-topics=we-have-a-topic&filter-featured=&filter-rating=
```

Can I not add these to the query string if they are not set? `!isset()` or is there another way to do this?

Comment: why do you care for that? What do you want to do with the data on the next page?

Comment: You could add a Javascript handler to the onSubmit event and use it to disable any empty fields before submitting the form. Disabled fields aren't submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively manipulate the form inputs thru javascript, just a Mike said in the comments, on submit check the fields, if empty, disable them so that they wont be included on submission.

This is just the basic idea (with jQuery):

```
<form method="GET" id="form_inputs">
    <input type="text" name="field1" value="field_with_value" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" value="" /><br/><!-- empty field -->
    <input type="text" name="field3" value="field_with_value" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" id="submit_form" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[name="submit_form"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form').children().each(function(i, e){
        if($(e).is('input') && $(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            // or $(this).attr('name', '');
        }
    });
    $('form').submit();
});
</script>
```

Or if you do not want to use jquery at all:

```
document.getElementById('submit_form').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var children = document.getElementById('form_inputs').childNodes;
    for(i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if(children[i].type == 'text' && children[i].value == '') {
            children[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('form_inputs').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason all those keys show up in query string is because they exist as inputs in the form. If you don't want them sent, remove them from the form, or at least give them some meaningful defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking a condition

```
 if (!empty($_POST['var'])) {

 }
```

OR

```
 if (!isset($_POST['var']) && !empty($_POST['var'])) {

 }
```